# Nginx or Apache in RoR application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache, nginx

I would like to ask which server to choose Apache or Nginx to host the application in RoR.
The whole works on a dedicated server 8 cores, 16GB of memory. The application is a content reader, with a fairly advanced file management. The most important criterion is the speed of serving content to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nginx + Unicorn should be ideal fot this case

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest case NGINX wll be faster with serving content.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx + Thin ([Macournoyer](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/)) and use nginx's cache for the static content.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx will perform better than apache.It will be faster.